# django oauth request with bearer token returns "relative imports require the 'package' argument" error

Tags: python, django, oauth, django-oauth

I am trying to implement the django oauth toolkit by following this tutorial:

https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial_03.html

But I can't get past this step as the curl get request at the bottom of the page returns the error

```
relative imports require the 'package' argument
```

I've completed the first part of the tutorial exactly as instructed and it is all working fine up to this point.
I'm using django 1.8.

Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong version of django-auth-toolkit, the latest version 1.0.0 only supports Django 1.10, 1.11. Reverting back to 0.12.0 solved the problem for me.